# Nested array aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I obtain the sum of all the first elements in each of the arrays in this document using the MongoDB aggregation framework?

```
{
    items: {
        item1: [5, 8, 2],
        item2: [4, 3, 1],
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is the partial pipeline I've tried:

```
[{
  $addFields: {
    itemsAsArray: {
      $objectToArray: '$items'
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    itemsAsArray: 1
  }
}, {
  $unwind: '$itemsAsArray'
}]
```

So I take this `items` value from the document that was matched, convert it to an array, and unwind it. Now I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{
    itemsAsArray: {
        k: 'item1',
        v: [5, 8, 2]
    }
},
{
    itemsAsArray: {
        k: 'item2',
        v: [4, 3, 1]
    }
}, ... ]
```

With this array, how can I group them to yield the sum of the first element in each of the arrays now denoted as `v`? Am I on the right track?

Comment: what should be the output ?

Comment: I'm looking for the sum of the first element in each of the arrays originally labeled item1, item2, etc.

Comment: in `item1` first element is 5 so with which we add  5?

Comment: so in this example the result should be 9, 5 + 4